# E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) Can't install any dpkg or cant update i tried mny methods but not worked

Tags: kali-linux

```
dpkg: error processing package kali-desktop-xfce (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-3) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 php7.4-common
 php7.4-mysql
 php7.4-readline
 php7.4-cli
 grub-pc
 unattended-upgrades
 php7.4
 libnma-common
 php7.4-opcache
 libapache2-mod-php7.4
 php7.4-json
 libnma0:i386
 network-manager-openvpn-gnome
 network-manager-pptp-gnome
 libnma-dev:i386
 gir1.2-nma-1.0:i386
 network-manager-gnome
 network-manager-l2tp-gnome
 network-manager-vpnc-gnome
 kali-desktop-xfce
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

[image]

Comment: What's your distro? Please post the complete output - looks like a lot is missing. Do **not** post screenshots of text terminals. Run `sudo apt-get update` prior to running any commands.

Comment: What were you trying to do when you got that error?  Was it a simple `apt upgrade` or were you installing something?  If installing, was it something from the official repository?  Were you attempting to upgrade from one suite to another?

Comment: Any chance you still have the terminal running that, and can scroll up? The significant error is somewhere above...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest running the following:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt --fix-broken install
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

Then repeat until the errors are all gone or repeat reliably. That usually solves normal dist-upgrade problems (which I am assuming is what you were doing).

If that doesn't work, then there's probably an issue with your sources.  In that case please post the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list`.